# Can't get Jcarousel to work, followed the instructions

Tags: javascript

This what I have done.

1. Get [Jcarousel](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/jcarousel-7.x-2.7.zip) module and install.
2. Got [Jcarousel Pluggin](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/archive/0.3.3.zip) zipped files
3. Created the sites/all/libraries/jquery.jcarousel folder
4. Moved the content of the downloaded folder into the sites/all/libraries/jquery.jcarousel folder

Now this is where there is a problem.

> When this is done there should be a file sites/all/libraries/jquery.jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js **or** jquery.jcarousel.min.js

There is no such file.

Where do I get those files?
I've tried to copy-paste the files from sites/all/libraries/jquery.jcarousel/dist, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Jcarousel module and it works. The directory in the `libraries` folder is like this

[image]

and it works. I downloaded the module's library from

> https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel

and Those files are under `dist` and `src` directory

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the documentation.

> When this is done there should be a file sites/all/libraries/jquery.jcarousel/**lib**/jquery.jcarousel.js or  jquery.jcarousel.min.js

*lib* should be *libs*.